# Finding the `card` function

Tags: isabelle

I am confused as to where the function for determining the set cardinality is precisely located. If I look 
in `Cardinality.thy` there is nothing to be found, but `Phantom_Type` is imported which in turn imports `Main`, where at least an abbreviation of `card` is to found (though not the definition of `card` itself).

Answer (score 0):

Just ctrl-click on the term ‘card’ in Isabelle/jEdit and it will take you straight to the definition in `Finite_Set.thy`:

```
text ‹
  The traditional definition
  @{prop "card A ≡ LEAST n. ∃f. A = {f i |i. i < n}"}
  is ugly to work with.
  But now that we have @{const fold} things are easy:
›

global_interpretation card: folding "λ_. Suc" 0
  defines card = "folding.F (λ_. Suc) 0"
  by standard rule
```

This uses the `folding` locale, which provides an operation to fold (i.e. iterate) over the elements of a finite set.

I'm not sure what abbreviation you are thinking of. If you mean the `CARD('a)` thing, that is just some syntax for `card (UNIV :: 'a set)`, i.e. the cardinality of the type `'a`.